# Loading an image with SQLi and PHP

Tags: php, database, image, mysqli

So I'm trying to display a list of products from the database. Everything loads fine but the image, I just get a bunch of random text. I'm guessing it could have something to do with the way I set up the image in the database? I did use BLOB and pre-set an image which is in the database to be assigned to that product.

Random appearing text:
http://prntscr.com/d9jcsz

Database:
http://prntscr.com/d9jcye

Code:

```
  $sql="SELECT * FROM products";
$result=mysqli_query($db, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row["name"]." | ".$row["price"]." | ".$row["description"]; 
    echo $row["image"];
    echo '<input type="button" value="Purchase"';
    echo '<br>';
    }
```

Any help much appreciated!
Thanks